# How to insert on different databases tables at the same transaction on a trigger in sql server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a trigger on UPDATE that must insert a row in two tables of different databases, if I comment the second INSERT statement it works if I don't then it does not work at all, how can i solve this?

Here is the code:

```
    BEGIN TRY                                   
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- MANAGER Table
        INSERT INTO DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE (
            IDTARJETA, CAJA, FECHA, TIPO, CODIGO, DESCRIPCION, PUNTOS, CONSUMICIONES,
            IMPORTE, TICKETS, Z, SERIE, NUMERO, N, ALIAS
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @idTarjeta, @caja, @fecha, 1, 0, @descripcion, @puntos, 1,
            @saldo_recargado, 1, 0, @serie, @numero, 'B', ' '
        );

        -- DBFREST Table
        INSERT INTO DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE (
            IDTARJETA, CAJA, FECHA, TIPO, CODIGO, DESCRIPCION, PUNTOS, CONSUMICIONES,
            IMPORTE, TICKETS, Z, SERIE, NUMERO, N, ALIAS
        )
        SELECT
            IDTARJETA, CAJA, FECHA, TIPO, CODIGO, 
            DESCRIPCION, PUNTOS, CONSUMICIONES,
            IMPORTE, TICKETS, Z, SERIE, NUMERO, N, ALIAS
        FROM DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE 
        WHERE NUMERO = @numero
        AND SERIE = @serie;
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO DATABASE1.dbo.APPS_ERRORS
    VALUES
    (   
        SUSER_SNAME(),
        ERROR_NUMBER(),
        ERROR_STATE(),
        ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        ERROR_LINE(),
        ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        GETDATE()
    );
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Found out the error: different datatype in column CAJA table 1 is a VARCHAR and table 2 is a INT.

Comment: Aside: This is clearly only part of the code in the trigger. It doesn't reference either the `inserted` or `deleted` tables. Hopefully it is designed to process all of the updated rows and is not based on the assumption that only one row will be affected by an `update` statement.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO DATABASE1.dbo.APPS_ERRORS` in the `catch` clause should be after the `rollback transaction`, otherwise it will be rolled back with the first two inserts.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the logging will be rolled back regardless because triggers execute in the context of the statement that fired the trigger. The explict transaction in the trigger code is actually nested and a `ROLLBACK` in a trigger aborts the entire batch. Bottom line is that the catch block here should just `THROW`.